# Full calendar problema con deshabilitar dias anteriores

Tags: javascript, html, plugin, calendar

Antes de empezar el post quiero saludarlos.

Mi cuestión es la siguiente, estoy intentando deshabilitar o hacer que aparezca un "no se puede crear eventos en días que ya terminaron" usando el full calendar, al igual que intento deshabilitar o mandar un mensaje que diga "no se puede crear evento en la fecha seleccionada" que se encuentre a futuro para días festivos o cosas por el estilo. El caso es que es para la función de click, no para la de seleccionar varios días. Por lo que no sé como hacerlo y tengo un buen rato intentándolo. Acá dejo lo que tengo.

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        locale: 'es',
        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
      header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next, month'
      },

      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      weekends: false,


      dateClick: function(info) {
        var actual = new Date();
     if(info > actual){
      alert(info.date);
    info.dayEl.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    $("#exampleModal").modal();
    document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML= info.dateStr;
}
else{
alert("Esto no es posible amigo");}
}
    });

    calendar.render();

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma en la que lo logré hacer es la siguiente. Para futuras referencias

```
  dateClick: function(info) {
  var actual = new Date();
  if(info.date >= actual){
    info.dayEl.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    $("#exampleModal").modal();
    document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML= info.dateStr;
  }else{
    alert("Error: No se puede solicitar una cita en una fecha vencida");
  }
```

}
    });

```
calendar.render();
```

});